# How to set different styles for Android and iOS in Ionic

Tags: android, css, ios, ionic-framework

Is it possible to set different styles when my app is on an IOS or Android device in HTML or CSS?

For example, IOS devices space out `<ion-title>` differently than Android devices.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with **different code** you mean the style or functionality?

Comment: For example. if I am on Android, then run a part of a CSS class. If I am on IOS, then run another part of a CSS class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you can use something like this.

```
.ios ion-title {
    color: black;
}
.md ion-title {
    color: blue;
}
```

Also you can check it out the official documentation here [Ionic Platform Style](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-styles)

Comment: Can't believe how easy that was, when ifNg didn't want to work properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me in Ionic3 however the following did.  I am targeting my component GotosComp displayed via ModalController and wanted some margin around it on the mobile running from the web (PWA).  Apparently the margin is there automatically when I run in desktop mode browser/responsive.

```
.platform-mobile {
    GotosComp {
        margin: 10vmin;
        height: 50vh;
        width: 80vw;
    }
}
```

Also you can use .platform-core if you wanted to target just the desktop browser
[image]
Perhaps it will help someone.